# Edit a SharePoint lookup field link from the linked "child" record

Tags: sharepoint, lookup-field

I have two lists in SharePoint, one each for projects and tasks, that I need to relate through the use of a lookup field.

If I create the lookup field in the project list then I can assign multiple tasks to the project and easily see what tasks are assigned to the project and click through to the project. I cannot, however, see what project tasks are assigned to in the task views.

If I create the lookup field in the task list, then I can easily choose which project to assign it to and I can sort or filter the task list view by project using the values in the lookup field, but I can't easily see which tasks are assigned to any given project in the project list view.

If I have to choose one or the other, the latter is the better option since the list of projects is shorter than the list of tasks and I can always filter on the project name in the lookup field column in the task list view.

Ideally, however, I would like to easily be able to see which tasks are assigned to a project from within the project list view, and maybe even edit the relationship from there.

Is there any way to do this in SharePoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the following solution seems to be working pretty well and does not involve the use of any new web parts or custom code.

I have the lookup field (with select multiple **disabled**) in the task list (the child list).

As stated in the question, the lookup list for the projects is much shorter and easier to use than the lookup field for the tasks. This also allows me to go into the tasks list view and filter on the lookup field (which is also a link to the respective project).

To facilitate easy access to the tasks for any given project, I added a link field to the project and link to the list view that is filtered for that particular project's tasks.

This keeps the list structure simple but allows me to quickly jump between the two lists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you keep the 2 lookup but I don't recommend that the other way around is to create a custom listing web part thru SharePoint API and get the tasks related to each projects

Comment: Thanks for your answer baberak. I thought about using a content query web part, but I want to first try to find a solution within the "out of the box" list settings. I think I found a workaround (see my answer).

Comment: yep it's nice as long as it's doing what you want @ the end user inteface